# only current active class, should get listener's call back, instead of all class, java

Tags: java, android

This is question related Java, I have used one BaseActivity that implements interface

```
import io.socket.IOAcknowledge;
import io.socket.IOCallback;
import io.socket.SocketIO;
import io.socket.SocketIOException;

/**
 * Created by amit on 11/12/15.
 */
public class BaseActivity extends Activity implements IOCallback {

    public ArrayList<Users> mUserList = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<String> mRoomList = new ArrayList<>();


    SocketIO mSocket;

    {
        try {
            mSocket = new SocketIO(Constants.CHAT_SERVER_URL);
            mSocket.connect(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onDisconnect() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnect() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge ack) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack) {

    }

    @Override
    public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(SocketIOException socketIOException) {

    }
}
```

Because of **mSocket.connect(this);** should call only once I have created BaseActivity and I have extended into all Activity

for example

```
public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity {
  @Override
public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Server said:" + json.toString(2));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge ack) {
    System.out.println("Server said: " + data);
}

@Override
public void onError(SocketIOException socketIOException) {
    System.out.println("an Error occured");
    socketIOException.printStackTrace();
}

@Override
public void onDisconnect() {
    System.out.println("Connection terminated.");
}

@Override
public void onConnect() {
    System.out.println("Connection established");
}

@Override
public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args) {
```

Another class also has same

```
 public class ListOfActivity extends BaseActivity {
  @Override
public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Server said:" + json.toString(2));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge ack) {
    System.out.println("Server said: " + data);
}

@Override
public void onError(SocketIOException socketIOException) {
    System.out.println("an Error occured");
    socketIOException.printStackTrace();
}

@Override
public void onDisconnect() {
    System.out.println("Connection terminated.");
}

@Override
public void onConnect() {
    System.out.println("Connection established");
}

@Override
public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args) {
```

My problem is that whenever any event fired, all Activities which are in stack, events are fired instead of only current visible activity

I can handle it by onResume on onPause with boolean flag,

but I think i am doing wrong way, is there any-other way then please suggest me

because of I want to call this **mSocket.connect** only one times, but it has listener, I have to implement on every class

Comment: Use onPause() and onResume(). In onResume you call socket.connect() and in onPause you call socket.disconnect();

Comment: @ElDuderino but I don't want to call disconnect and connect every activity instead in whole application i want to call connect only one time that's why]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Service`. Keep all your socket connection/disconnection methods in there. Bind your `Activities` to this service so that you will only be using one socket at a time.

Another solution is to use singletons. Whether or not singletons are a good idea in your case is best determined by you. Nonetheless, if you are hell bent on not wanting to connect/disconnect sockets from every activity, have a look at extending the `Application` class.(This `Application` subclass that you create has a much longer lifecycle than an `Activity`).

Have a look [here](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/) and [here](https://www.mobomo.com/2011/05/how-to-use-application-object-of-android/)

Also, in any case, use appropriate synchronization mechanisms to be sure which Activity is writing what via the shared socket.